# Takes user input string and convert it to secret code from hash

Tags: ruby

I was given a code challenge of taking a user input and converting that input using the following cipher information:

```
replace = {
  "A" => "Z",
  "B" => "Y",
  "C" => "X",
  "D" => "W",
  "E" => "V",
  "F" => "U",
  "G" => "T",
  "H" => "S",
  "I" => "R",
  "J" => "Q",
  "K" => "P",
  "L" => "O",
  "M" => "N",
  "N" => "M",
  "O" => "L",
  "P" => "K",
  "Q" => "K",
  "R" => "I",
  "S" => "H",
  "T" => "G",
  "U" => "F",
  "V" => "E",
  "W" => "D",
  "X" => "C",
  "Y" => "B",
  "Z" => "A"
}
```

This is my code:

```
puts "Time to decipher some code: "
input = gets.chomp.upcase
replace.each do |k, v| 
  input.gsub!(k,v)
end
puts input
```

In my `each` block, my cipher doesn't seem to properly convert. Can anyone explain why this might be?

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to properly convert" mean?  Please show the input, the actual output, and what the output should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
replace = {
  "A" => "Z",
  "B" => "Y",
  "C" => "X",
  "D" => "W",
  "E" => "V",
  "F" => "U",
  "G" => "T",
  "H" => "S",
  "I" => "R",
  "J" => "Q",
  "K" => "P",
  "L" => "O",
  "M" => "N",
  "N" => "M",
  "O" => "L",
  "P" => "K",
  "Q" => "K",
  "R" => "I",
  "S" => "H",
  "T" => "G",
  "U" => "F",
  "V" => "E",
  "W" => "D",
  "X" => "C",
  "Y" => "B",
  "Z" => "A"
}

puts "Time to decipher some code: "
input = gets.chomp.upcase

output = ""
input.each_char do |c|
    output << replace[c]
end
puts output
```

Comment: Or: `output = input.each_char.with_object('') {|c, out| out << replace[c] }`

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating through the hash `replace` rather than the `input` string. So, if your `input = "HELLO"`...

```
Input: HELLO
Input: HVLLO
Input: SVLLO
Input: SVOOO
Input: SVLLL   #changing back O to L
Input: HVLLL   #changing back S to H
Input: HELLL   #changing back V to E
```

Since you're iterating through `replace` you will end up switching letters more than once.

My solution to this problem would have been to iterate through each of the letters in `input` and then replace them according to `replace`. In order to iterate through `input` I would have to split it and then eventually join it later into a string.

Comment: You don't have to split a string to iterate over its characters. That's what `each_char` is for

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not Ruby-specific. It is a very very very elementary (school) level algorithm mistake. You got your result because the replaced characters can later match to be replaced with something else.

It is reminiscent of a mistake when one has variables `a = "foo"` and `b = "bar"` and is trying to switch their values, doing:

```
b = a
a = b
```

---

A typical way to do it correctly is:

```
input.gsub!(/./, Hash.new{|_, k| k}.merge(replace))
```

Comment: It works fine for single word but what about none existing keys or white space? anyways 1+

Comment: @GaganGami Good point. I did't assume such characters. I fixed it.

Comment: now it looks more pretty. I wish I could upvote more then 1 time. :D

Answer (score 1):

```
input = gets.chomp.upcase
p input.gsub(/[A-Z]/, replace)
```

The mysterious `/[A-Z]/` part is a regular expression, which searches a string for any uppercase character. `gsub` then replaces it with what's in the `replace` hash.

Comment: Yours is better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for all of the help! I was able to solve it using many of your posts, but Raman's seemed to be the simplest.

```
replace = {
  "A" => "Z",
  "B" => "Y",
  "C" => "X",
  "D" => "W",
  "E" => "V",
  "F" => "U",
  "G" => "T",
  "H" => "S",
  "I" => "R",
  "J" => "Q",
  "K" => "P",
  "L" => "O",
  "M" => "N",
  "N" => "M",
  "O" => "L",
  "P" => "K",
  "Q" => "K",
  "R" => "I",
  "S" => "H",
  "T" => "G",
  "U" => "F",
  "V" => "E",
  "W" => "D",
  "X" => "C",
  "Y" => "B",
  "Z" => "A"
}

puts "Time to decipher some code: "
input = gets.chomp.upcase

output = ""
input.each_char do |c|
    output << replace[c]
end

puts output
```